# How to allow a user to enter a password when deleting an authorization in devise/omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have a rais 3 app that uses devise and omniauth to allow users to register/login via their twitter account and/or with local login credentials.  Everything works fine for registering and logging in.  My problem occurs when a user chooses to destroy their twitter authorization without first establishing a local password.   If a user destroys their authorizations, then I would like to route them to new_password_path so that they can choose a password for future log-ins.

Here is the controller code:

```
   class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create, :failure]

      def create
        omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
        if authentication #existing user is logging-in with existing authentication service
          flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
          set_home_location_cookies(authentication.user, authentication.user.home_lat, authentication.user.home_lng)
          sign_in(:user, authentication.user)
          redirect_to root_path
        elsif current_user #existing user who is already logged-in is creating a new authentication service for future use
          current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => omniauth['credentials']['token'])
          current_user.update_posting_preferences(omniauth['provider'])
          flash[:notice] = "Successfully linked to your #{omniauth['provider'].titleize} account."
          redirect_to root_path
        else #new user is creating a new authentication service and logging in
          user = User.new
          user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
          if user.save
            flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
            sign_in(:user, user)
            redirect_to root_path
          else
            session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
            session[:user_message] = {:success => false, :message => "userSaveError"}
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
         end
        end
      end


      def failure
        flash[:alert] = "Could not authorize you from your social service."
        redirect_to root_path
      end

      def destroy
        @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
        current_user.update_posting_preferences(@authentication.provider)
        @authentication.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "You have successfully destroyed your link to your #{@authentication.provider.titleize} account."
        if current_user.authentications.empty? && current_user.encrypted_password.empty?
          sign_out
          flash[:alert] = "Alert: Your account does not currently have a password for account authorization.  You are in danger of losing your account unless you create a new password by using this form."
          redirect_to new_password_path(current_user) and return
        else
          redirect_back_or(root_path)
        end
      end
```

The code results in a "could not find valid mapping for nil" error triggered by my `redirect_to new_password_path(current_user) and return` command
 [image]

I would greatly appreciate some help figuring out this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I'll admit it.  I implemented the authentications controller from a tutorial without studying devise routing to learn what was going on behind the scenes.  Last night I reviewed the docs and figured out my problem.  What is funny is that the above routine did work on an older version of devise but does not work on devise 1.5.3.

In the destroy action I sign-out the current_user then I try to route to the new_password_path sending in "current_user" as a parameter.  Not surprisingly, at that point "current_user" has been nulled out.  So, I get the, "could not find a valid mapping for nil" error.  Here is my easy fix:

```
  def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    user = current_user
    current_user.update_posting_preferences(@authentication.provider)
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully destroyed your link to your #{@authentication.provider.titleize} account."
    if current_user.authentications.empty? && current_user.encrypted_password.empty?
      sign_out
      flash[:alert] = "Alert: Your account does not currently have a password for account authorization.  You are in danger of losing your account unless you create a new password by using this form."
      redirect_to new_password_path(user) and return
    else
      redirect_back_or(root_path)
    end
  end
```